# Setting up a Com Port

Tags: batch-file, serial-communication

I'm having an issue with a COM port not sending commands until I open up HyperTerminal.  If I connect one RS232 cable from COM1 port to COM2 port, I can send messages back and forth using two instances of HyperTerminal.  Once a connection is established, I can then disconnect from COM2 and connect it to the hardware that needs the message, and it will execute just fine.  I have to do this every time I restart the PC, otherwise nothing will happen.

I'm using a batch file to send the commands with this line:
echo hello>com1

We're also running on Windows XP.

Comment: Use the MODE command.  Type mode /? to get usage help.

Comment: I've never tried using the serial port from a batch file, but try having a look at `MODE /?` ... something like `MODE COM1: BAUD=19200` ... there are several other options for controlling flow-control etc.

Comment: The mode is actually set properly by default, but I have added setting the mode to the bat file, to no avail.  It's acting as if it doesn't recognize there's even a connection until after HyperTerminal is used.  From then on, the connection works fine and the hardware receives all messages.

Comment: Have you compared the output of `MODE COM1` immediately after a reboot (when it's not working) with after having used Hyperterm?

Comment: I just checked and they're identical. baud - 9600, data bits - 8, Parity - None, Stop Bits - 1, Flow Control - None

Comment: For some reason, COM2 works every time.  So that will be my solution.  Thanks for the help Tripe and Hans!